# the apk file working in emulator but not in android device

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, android

I run an application in Android emulator in my p.c.  , it is working properly .

but,

when I connect my Android device with p.c. , then through eclipse , I run the application , eclipse prompt that whether you want to install your application in android emulator or Android device , I choose Android device ,, the device  prompt a force to close error !!!!

even in my laptop the application were installed properly , but not working properly ...

what could be the reason ????

my current Android device version is 2.3.6

thanks...

Comment: check your log cat what error you are getting this may be because network failure or gps or any other reason give logcat

Comment: when I run the application on device , there is no logCat error...

Comment: are you installing with an data cable ??

Comment: ok then go to your ddms and select your device there in left side block you will get a log flood

Comment: is this silly question ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the issue is because what you described isn't specific. Have you ever been able to install any application on the device? Is it just this one application that doesn't install?

The first things I would check:

1. Do you have the correct Windows USB driver installed?

   The Android developers website has a page dedicated to it ( http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html ) but you should check the manufacturer's website for the most up-to-date software.
2. Do you have the developer settings enabled on the device?

   Settings > Applications > Enable Unknown Sources

   Settings > Applications > Development > Enable USB Debugging

Comment: the application is installed correctly but not working properly..
there is a login page I enter the user name and password  it prompt the force to close error .. the same  application is working correctly in another Android device ..